# Trouble with font family css property in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

the css properties for font family not being executed in firefox but perfect in chrome.

attaching screen shots of element inspector in firefox and chrome[image: Firefox element inspector]

[image: Chrome element inspector]

```
body {
  background: #fefefe;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Roboto' sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS rather than images?

Comment: body {
    background: #fefefe;
    color: #777;
    font-family:'Roboto' sans-serif !important; 
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`font-family` values are supposed to be comma-separated. It’s not unlikely that some browsers interpret your font family name as “'Roboto' sans-serif”.

Comment: A fiddle that can be used to test browser behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/2tkhbxp6/1/. In Safari, the incorrect definition is styled in Georgia, which means it does not see Helvetica in ``font-family: Helvetica serif;`` declaration.

Comment: ..!!!!! commas and semicolons are the ones that i have a habit of forgetting...!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Helvetica is not a standard web-safe font, try to use

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

You can also download that font and link it.

Or try to use similar font form googlefonts https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed